# jquery fade in issues

Tags: jquery, fadein

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
$('#1a,#2a,#3a,#5a,#6a').click(show_hide);
function show_hide() {
    // function logic
    $('#cont6').hide();
    $('#cont5').hide();
    $('#cont4').hide();

    $('#cont3').hide();
    $('#cont2').hide();

    $('#cont1').fadeIn("slow");
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7) {
        this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
    }
}
```

});

The above script doesnt works, can any one tell me whats wrong with it . thanks

Comment: What would it do if it worked?

Comment: :-( please dont use a number as the 1st character in your DOM IDs....

Comment: welll on clicking the id it will hide content on the page within the id written above, ok will change the id from number to something else

Comment: Which line fails ? if you add the HTML we can investigate a lot better

Comment: it works now the id was an issue thnx everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the IDs used on the following line to not use numbers as the first character

```
$('#1a,#2a,#3a,#5a,#6a').click(show_hide);
```

IDs starting with numbers are invalid.

Comment: This is true, but it's probably not causing the code to fail. Browsers usually tolerate IDs that start with a number.

Comment: @mblase75 the latest versions of common browsers do tend to tolerate numerical starting IDs. However the standard says they shouldn't and jQuery doesn't work with them either.